# How can I bring the local variable value (sales and commission) to main method?

Tags: c#, methods

I have to create 2 methods to complete the program. First method collects the sales via user input and returns value to main. Second methods calculates the commission and returns the final commission. We have to calculate the commission at the end of the program.

```
namespace Lab_4
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static double GetSales()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter your sales");
            double sales = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            return sales;
        }
        static double GetCommission(double sales)
        {
            if (sales >= 0 && sales <=999)
            {
                double commission = sales * 0.03;
                return commission;
            }
            else
            {
                if (sales >= 1000 && sales <= 2999)
                {
                    double commission = sales * 0.04;
                    return commission;
                }
                else
                {
                    if (sales >= 3000)
                    {
                        double commission = sales * 0.05;
                        return commission;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
 
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetSales();
            GetCommission();
        }
    }
}
```

I simply can't figure out how to do this correctly. How do extract the values from sales and commissions which are local variables? The first method works fine. But the 2nd one doesn't read the sales value.

Comment: Read how to use functions in c# or most of other languages work in similar way. Getsales returns sales store this in a local variable in main method then pass it as parameter to getcommission function call in main method.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're returning the values of `GetSales` and `GetCommission`, you can store the results by assigning them to a variable:

```
double sales = GetSales();
double commission = GetCommission(sales);
```

Which you can then use those variables to your heart content.

Comment: I get the following error:
Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'sales' of 'Program.GetCommission(double)'

Comment: I've edited my question. Take a look at the new edit.